# How can auto generate war file for java maven project in GitLab?

Tags: maven, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

How can auto generate war file for java maven project in GitLab, once the developer commit the code in gitlab repository automatic generate war ?

Answer (score 0):

Add a [custom hook to your GitLab repo](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/administration/custom_hooks.html)

> Hooks can be placed in `hooks/<hook_name>.d` (global) or `custom_hooks/<hook_name>.d` (per project) directories supporting chained execution of the hooks.

In your case: `<project>.git/custom_hooks/<hook_name>` on the server side: that hook can, when receiving new commits, build the war.

Comment: what i am thinking it's i upload my maven project in gitlab , then generate file **.gitlab-ci.yml** on root project of gitlab contains the follwing :
 image: ng-maven

maven_build:
  script: 
  - cd POC/mavenproject
  - mvn package
  artifacts:
    untracked: true

Comment: the maven already generate war project it's possible get this war after job finished?

Comment: @anashijazy possible through its URL: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/pipelines/job_artifacts.html#downloading-the-latest-job-artifacts